# Need suggestions on how to change height and width using desired capabilities in chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, emulation

I am using selenium webdriver with chrome desired capabilities to work on a desktop browser in emulation mode.And i need to change the height and width attributes after certain lines of my code. Below is the extract I am using to launch the emulated chrome browser. But how do i change the height and width attributes without having to relaunch the browser again.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe"); 

Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 900);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 700);
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 4.0);

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like   Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53");

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I need to change the width as 700 and height as 900. Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** My initial answer was that all you need is:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize( new Dimension(700, 900) );
```

(Here's the [full details](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#set-window-size) of the method from the WebDriver spec. Provided you have a window open, you can call it whenever you like.)

However, this **doesn't** work at all. It merely resizes the overall browser frame, which is useless as Chrome uses the original mobile-emulation dimensions to create **its own inner frame**, which cannot be resized using WebDriver methods. (Which is fair enough, as this is Chrome-specific functionality.)

For example, when I run the original attached code, the window size turns out to be (1247, 1319), so resizing it to be (700,900) just reduces the overall frame size, causing the inner frame to scroll.

I haven't found any other information about modifying Chrome Options during runs, so I can only conclude that this **isn't** possible.